# Optimizing recursive code for generating valid arrays from input array

Tags: python, recursion, optimization

I have a recursive Python function that generates valid output arrays from an input array containing different "types" of elements representing different days of the week, e.g. `[m1, m2, m3, m4, t1, t2, t3, t4, w1, w2, w3, w4]`.

To address my needs, I was able to figure out a recursive function (help from another stack overflower) that could take input arrays and return valid arrays according the constraints:

1. If an element from a specific day is present, there must be at least four of them.
2. The elements from a certain day must be sequential.
3. Must be twelve elements in total

**Example input**

`[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,t1,t2,t3,t4,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3,f4]`.

**Example output:**

`[m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12]` (can be all of one type since others not present)

`[m5,m6,m7,m8,m9,m10,m11,m12,t1,t2,t3,t4]` (or at least 4 of each type in order)

`[m4,m5,m6,m7,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3,f4]` (at least 4 of each type if present, but can be missing) etc.

**Invalid:**

`[m4,m6,m5,m7,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3,f4]` (out of order)

`[m4,m5,m6,m7,m8,w1,w2,w3,w4,f1,f2,f3]` (not 4 of each type)

**The code that works:**

```py
import collections
import re

data =  ['f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7', 't8', 't9', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7', 'r8', 'r9', 'm0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3']

def combo(d, c = []):
  if len(c) == 12:
     yield c
  else:
     for i in d:
        _count1 = collections.Counter([re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', j)[0] for j in c])
        _count2 = collections.Counter([re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', j)[0] for j in c+[i]])
        if i not in c:
           if len(c) < 11 or all(b >= 4 for b in _count2.values()):
              if re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', i)[0] in _count1:
                 if int(re.findall('\d+$', i)[0])-1 == int(re.findall('\d+$', c[-1])[0]) and re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', i)[0] == re.findall('^[a-zA-Z]+', c[-1])[0]:
                    yield from combo(d, c+[i])
              else:
                 yield from combo(d, c+[i])

result = combo(data)

print(next(result))
```

**Output**

```py
 ['f13','f14','f15','f16','w0','w1','w2','w3','t4','t5','t6','t7']
```

This function successfully returns a correct/valid schedule, but to get the first successful result, **it takes 299 seconds**. Is there a way to optimize the code, or process the input array in some way to make it so that these results can be returned faster? Thank you

Edit for clarification:

I need to have a function (like the one I have now) **that generates all possible outputs for an input** that is valid according to the constraints I have, preferably in a generator like way so I can loop through it one at a time when needed to see if that combination works in my program or not.

**For example, using the same input,**

```py
data =  ['f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17', 'w0', 'w1', 'w2', 'w3', 't4', 't5', 't6', 't7', 't8', 't9', 'r4', 'r5', 'r6', 'r7', 'r8', 'r9', 'm0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3']
```

**I could have output like**

```py
 ['f13','f14','f15','f16','w0','w1','w2','w3','t4','t5','t6','t7']

 ['f14','f15','f16','f17','w0','w1','w2','w3','t4','t5','t6','t7']

 ['f13','f14','f15','f16','r4','r5','r6','r7','t4','t5','t6','t7']
```

etc.

**Using different input**

```py
data =  ['m0','m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8','m9','m10','m11','t0','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']
```

**I could have output like**

```py
 ['m0','m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8','m9','m10','m11']

 ['m0','m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 't0','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4','t5']

 ['m0','m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4','t5']
```

etc

Note: for my needs, the following outputs would be equivalent, but it is not necessary to only be able to print one of them

```py
 ['m0','m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 't0','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4','t5']

 [ 't0','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5', 'm0','m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this code. I preprocess the data (make numbers from string and sort them) to not do `regex` in each iteration:

```
import re
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import combinations

data =  ['m0','m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8','m9','m10','m11','t0','t1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5']

# returns eg.:
# {'f': [13, 14, 15, 16, 17], 'w': [0, 1, 2, 3], 't': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'r': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 'm': [0, 1, 2, 3]}
def preprocess_data(data):
    out = {}
    for item in data:
        for k, v in re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)', item):
            out.setdefault(k, []).append(int(v))
    for k in out:
        out[k].sort()
    return out

# 1. if an element from a specific day is present, there must be atleast 4 of them
# 2. the elements from a certain day must be sequential <- they are, because we preprocessed the data
# 3. must be 12 total elements
def check(data):
    rv = {}
    keys = set()
    for k, v in data.items():
        for vv, gg in groupby(enumerate(v), lambda k: k[0]-k[1]):
            consecutive_elements = [ii[1] for ii in gg]

            keys.add(k)
            for i in range(4, len(consecutive_elements) + 1):
                rv.setdefault(k, []).append(consecutive_elements[:i])

            break

    for k in [*rv.keys()]:
        rv[k].append([])

    for c in combinations([(k, i) for k, v in rv.items() for i in v], len(rv)):
        if any(len(i[1]) < 4 for i in c if len(i[1]) > 0):
            continue

        elements = [i[0] for i in c]
        if len(elements) != len(set(elements)):
            continue

        c2 = tuple(i[0] + str(ii) for i in c for ii in i[1])

        if len(c2) == 12:
            yield c2

def get_valid_combinations(data, dont_rotate=[], seen=set()):
    for c in check(data):
        if c not in seen:
            seen.add(c)
            yield c

    for k, v in data.items():
        if k in dont_rotate:
            continue
        for n in range(len(v)):
            data[k] = v[n:] + v[:n]
            yield from get_valid_combinations(data, dont_rotate + [k], seen)

for a in get_valid_combinations(preprocess_data(data)):
    print(a)
```

Prints:

```
('m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3')
('m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11')
('m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m0', 'm1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3')
('m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m1', 'm2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3')
('m2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m2', 'm3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3')
('m3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m3', 'm4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3')
('m4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m4', 'm5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4')
('m5', 'm6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
('m6', 'm7', 'm8', 'm9', 'm10', 'm11', 't0', 't1', 't2', 't3', 't4', 't5')
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for answering. I may not have been clear in the original post, which has been edited.This does get me a quick answer, but only one answer. I need to have all possible answers that could work, preferably in a generator or something that gets it when needed since I loop through them one at a time until one works in my program (each one corresponds to specific days/hours that need to have space). The function only returns one answer I believe. Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you. it works great. I just had a question, I wasn't sure if it was possible. When getting results using something like next(a), is it possible to go through combinations in the function starting with the first type of day seen in the input array? For example, using the first input array I mentioned in question,
it gives me correct answers, but can i make it start with correct values with 'f', i.e. ['f13', 'f14', 'f15', 'f16'....] and then ['f14', 'f15', 'f16', 'f17'....] and then move on to next days? Either way, thank you very much for this answer.

Comment: @user3794422 you can load all results to array and the sort them by your needs.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was afraid this was the only way (returned all results doesn't work well because the input array can get rather large and returning all results can take upwards of 10 minutes for one input). Anyways, thanks for everything!